# can not assign props to data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

This is a simple component. I'm trying to assign `props` to `data` as [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) said so. (the `initialData` comes from vuex and database)

```
<template>
    <section>
        {{ initialData }}
        {{ privateData }}
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'someName',
    props: [
        'initialData'
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            privateData: this.initialData
        };
    }
 };
```

But, the problem is `initialData` is OK, but `privateData` is just an empty object `{}`.

Weirdest thing is, if I save my file again, so webpack hot reloads stuff, `privateData` also gets the proper data I need.

Here is the parent:

```
<template>
    <section v-if="initialData">
        <child :initial-data="initialData"></micro-movies>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'parentName',
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    computed: {
        initialData() {
            return this.$store.state.initialData;
        }
    },
    components: {
        child
    }
};
</script>
```

I know that it's about getting data dynamically . because if I change `initialData` in parent to some object manually, it works fine.

Comment: Use computed properties if your data is dependent on other data/property

Comment: Could you also show the code where you are passing the prop from the parent? The code here looks ok.

Comment: @RakeshSoni I did. and it works fine. but every data change needs `forceUpdate()`. I'm trying to change it to `data` so it auto update the component.

Comment: @SergiPasoev Ok. (It's something about getting data dynamically)

Comment: The data function is only ever called *once* at component creation. If `initialData` is not populated at that point in time, then `privateData` will always be null. That is why you probably want to use a computed property, or watch the property.

Comment: @Bert You're right. wanna write it as answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data function is only ever called *once* at component creation. If `initialData` is not populated at that point in time, then `privateData` will always be null. That is why you probably want to use a computed property, or watch the property.